# Add table row on pressing tab on last td

Tags: jquery

Lets say we have just a simple table as below. I can navigate through the TD's by pressing the tab key.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I press tab on the last TD, I want to append a new TR.
I've tried many things, but I just can't make it work.

Hope someone has a solution!

Edit:

At the moment this is the script im trying to get worked.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 9) {
       var test = $(this).closest("td").next().find("td");
       console.log(test);

       $('tr:last td:last').addClass('last').css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});

       if($('td').hasClass("last")) {
           $(this).append('test');
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: _I've tried many things_ could you please show us some!

Comment: Please provide code... also the "many things" you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

**Javascript**

```
$('table').on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 9) return;
    var $this = $(this),
        $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('table')),
        $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
    if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
        $lastTr.after($lastTr.clone());
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/n4WZ3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean using input elements you could do something where you add an extra input element after the table and then add an on focus event to this element.

For example something such as this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="hideAddRow">
    <input type="text" id="addRow"/>
</div>
```

And the following js:

```
$('#addRow').on('focus', function () {
  alert('add new row code here.'); 
});
```

Or look at this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sGQ23/